# Why don't 3-phase AFDDs exist?

Tags: power-electronics, arc

Seems that commercial arc fault detection devices exist mainly in a 1P+N configuration. What about 3P+N? Are arc faults relevant when powering 3-phase equipment, and what can be done to mitigate them?

Comment: Use three single phase devices or get a three phase type to BS EN 62606

Comment: @Andyaka can you share link for a three phase type?